# Calculating average value of points around given point in a wider field

Tags: rust

I need to calculate the average value of points around a given point in a wider field.

For this I have a function:

```rust
fn local_average((x,y):(i32,i32),n:i32,(width,height):(i32,i32),space:&[i32]) -> i32 {
    let y_range = cmp::max(y-n,0)..cmp::min(y+n+1,height);
    let x_range = cmp::max(x-n,0)..cmp::min(x+n+1,width);
    println!("y: {:.?}, x: {:.?}",y_range,x_range);

    let size = (x_range.end-x_range.start) * (y_range.end-y_range.start);
    let mut total: i32 = 0;
    for yi in y_range {
        for xi in x_range.clone() {
            let i = yi * width + xi;
            total += space[i as usize]; 
        }
    }

    println!("{} / {} = {}",total,size,total / size);
    total / size
}
```

The thing that bothers me here is `x_range.clone()`, I feel like this is not a good approach.

I could also implement this in a more function manor but I'm unsure if this is  better as I find it to be less readable:

```rust
fn local_average_functional((x,y):(i32,i32),n:i32,(width,height):(i32,i32),space:&[i32]) -> i32 {
    let y_range = cmp::max(y-n,0)..cmp::min(y+n+1,height);
    let x_range = cmp::max(x-n,0)..cmp::min(x+n+1,width);
    println!("y: {:.?}, x: {:.?}",y_range,x_range);

    let size = (x_range.end-x_range.start) * (y_range.end-y_range.start);
    let total: i32 = y_range.map(|yl| {
        x_range.clone().map(|xl| {
            let il = yl * width as i32 + xl;
            space[il as usize] as i32
        }).sum::<i32>()
    }).sum();
    
    println!("{} / {} = {}",total,size,total / size);
    total / size
}
```

How could I improve this function?

Repl: https://repl.it/@JonathanWoollet/DraftyTautAdware

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't need an `x_range`. We need a range of proper indices over `space`, as it enables us to use `space[start..stop].iter().sum()`. We need a combination of `x_range` and `y_range`.

So let's start by building one from hand:

```rust
fn local_average((x, y): (i32, i32), n: i32, (width, height): (i32, i32), space: &[i32]) -> i32 {
    let y_range = cmp::max(y - n, 0)..cmp::min(y + n + 1, height);
    let x_range = cmp::max(x - n, 0)..cmp::min(x + n + 1, width);

    let size = (x_range.end - x_range.start) * (y_range.end - y_range.start);
    let mut total: i32 = 0;

    for yi in y_range {
        let start = (yi * width + x_range.start) as usize;
        let end = start + ((x_range.end - x_range.start) as usize);

        total += space[start..end].iter().sum::<i32>();
    }

    total / size
}
```

Note that the code above was **formatted by `rustfmt`**. The `rustfmt`-style is very common in Rust projects, and several projects reject contributions until they are properly formatted. For `cargo` based projects use `cargo fmt`.

Either way, we now replaced the inner loop by a single `sum()`, which is more explicit about our goal. This is also a mixture of both your code styles. At this point, we might as well replace `x_range` by `x_size`, but that's a question of style.

For an easier use of `local_average`, we could introduce `type Point = (i32, i32)` and `type Rect = (i32, i32)`, however, again, that's a matter of preference.

Comment: Maybe a little outside scope of question but in a case where `total:i32` and `space:[i8]` for example, would introducing a cast `space[start..end].iter().map(|x|*x as i32).sum::<i32>();` significantly affect performance? Would it be better to simply have `space` be a larger type for performance even if not needed for the data?

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light It's probably [slightly slower as the numbers get unpacked first](https://godbolt.org/z/scf613). However, I cannot give you any estimate how much slower this is going to be, sorry.